# OpenERP 7 How to give users access to custom module in OpenERP 7?

Tags: openerp-7

I have developed a custom Module in OpenERP 7, My administrator user can only see this module.

1-How can I give access to normal users to my custom modules?

2-What are the steps to solve this problem.

Please give a detailed example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a one `Security folder` which has below two files. For example,

- test_security.xml and
- ir.model.access.csv

**security/test_security.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_name_test">
            <field name="name">Management</field> 
            <field name="sequence">7</field>
        </record>

        <record id="group_name_test_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">User</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="group_name_test_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_name_test_user'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

After do this **Management** Option show with two selection value like User and Manager in `setting => Users => Access Rights => Application`

Now turn for **security/ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
unique_id, test.name, model_test_name, group_name_test_user, 1,1,0,0
unique_id, test.name, model_test_name, group_name_test_manager, 1,1,1,1
```

`test.name` is a table name.

**Example of csv file, how to create? Where**

- `Fields => Value => Description`
- `id` => `access_testing_for_user` => id must be unique.
- `name` => `testing.for.user` => name is given as we want.
- `model_id:id` => `model_test_name` => model_id:id is given like model_our_class_name.
- `group_id:id` => `group_name_test_user` => group_id:id is xml id of above we create like for User and Manager.
- `perm_read` => 1 for True and 0 for False for read record.
- `perm_write` => 1 for True and 0 for False for write record.
- `perm_create` => 1 for True and 0 for False for create record.
- `perm_unlink` => 1 for True and 0 for False for delete record.

**NOTE**

These two files `.xml and .csv` must be listed in `__openerp__.py` as other view files are given.

Comment: Thanks for answer I followed your steps, but I didn't see access right drop down to give normal users to my custom developed module, could you please explain more than this because I am new to OpenERP development.

Comment: have you mention `test_security.xml` file `__openerp__` file ?

Comment: Dear Odedra please could you explain how to create this csv file, and what are the standards to implement and what are those codes inside and how to create those codes.

Comment: in `.xml file`, we create a one menu in above path given e.g. Access Rights => Application. `.xml file` is used for the menu and which has two selection value e.g. User and Manager. If you select `User`, as per User rights given in csv file are applied on it. And for same 'Manager'. For particular menu rights we use `.xml id` in our `view.xml` file. And one important thing, these two files must be listed in the `__openerp__.py` as we give `other view files`.

Comment: Hello downvoter, you may welcome for give suggestion while give any answer for down vote, please add comment the reason. Because it will help a lot for improving the content. Thanks

Comment: Hi Odedra, can you suggest good learning material on general Odoo and security?

Comment: hi @AlexanderSuraphel, you may checkout this slideshare http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/openerp-security-in-openerp and but I always not found any powerful documentation of security in OpenERP/Odoo. One another found http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/04_security.html