# Openerp full access for a group

Tags: python, odoo

How to set full access to a group in my custom module in OpenErp?  Now some users doesn't have access everywhere because they are filtered by domain_filters.

Comment: For access right you can also make your own group and than you can give your desired rights to the user. For more help you can visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7/22534350#22534350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an **ir.model.access.csv** file, and give access rights to all the objects you want for the particular user group.

Answer (score 2):

You can set access rights from Menu :

**Settings --> Groups --> Access Rights** tab