# Odoo security guides and tutorials

Tags: odoo

I need any good guide or tutorials about Odoo security and how to manage it because the official Odoo documentation is very poor and I couldn't understand or get anything of it.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7) and [Here](http://www.serpentcs.com/serpentcs-security_in_openerp_groups_recordrules_access_rights) very helpful and understandable

Comment: There's also security in the python code itself. I've visited Odoo Experience last year and there was a presentation about the security. The slideshow can be found here: https://www.odoo.com/slides/slide/10-rules-for-safer-code-398