# Odoo fields access rights/rules

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

I want to make some of fields in record not editable for user who, is selected at field `forbridden_user`. But not all fields. Some of fields must still be editable for him. How could I achieve that?

Comment: might be helpful  to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7/22534350#22534350

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate issues here:

1. Making the field appear readonly in the form.
2. Securing it so it truly can not be modified.

Those are separate issues, and by addressing only the first point you can get a very unpleasant surprise in the future.

Unfortunately Odoo doesn't comes with a per-field permissions framework ([you can read my rant about this here](https://www.odoo.com/groups/community-59/community-10336007)).

If you want you can [use a module I created while working on a project, that addresses this very issue](https://github.com/EE/bestja/tree/master/addons/protected_fields).

After downloading the module and adding `protected_fields` to your module's dependencies you would do something like this:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'your.model'
    _inherit = [
        'protected_fields.mixin',
    ]
    _protected_fields = ['field_you_want_to_protect']

    field_you_want_to_protect = fields.Char()
    forbridden_user = fields.Many2one('res.users')
    current_user_forbidden = fields.Boolean(compute="_compute_current_user_forbidden")

    @api.one
    @api.depends('forbridden_user')
    def _compute_current_user_forbidden(self):
        """
        Compute a field indicating whether the current user
        shouldn't be able to edit some fields.
        """
        self.current_user_forbidden = (self.forbridden_user == self.env.user)

    @api.multi
    def _is_permitted(self):
        """
        Allow only authorised users to modify protected fields
        """
        permitted = super(DetailedReport, self)._is_permitted()
        return permitted or not self.current_user_forbidden
```

This will take care of securely protecting the field on the server side and additionally create a `current_user_forbidden` field. The field will be set to `True` when the *current* user is equal to `forbridden_user`. We can use this on client side to make the protected field appear readonly.

Add the computed field to your view (as an invisible field - we just need its value to be available) and add the `attrs` attribute to the field(s) you want to protect, with a domain that will make the field appear readonly when the `current_user_forbidden` field is to `True`:

```
<field name="current_user_forbidden" invisible="1"/>
<field name="field_you_want_to_protect" attrs="{'readonly': [('current_user_forbidden', '=', True)]}"/>
```

Of course instead of `field_you_want_to_protect` you should use your own field you want to protect.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is, ,
1) inherit the view 
 2) specify the groups to which you want to restrict the fields 
 3) then modify the field attributes.
I am pasting here the sample code, which will make Employee contirbution field readonly when Data Team group users logged in.

```
<record id="view_contribution_fields_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">member.contribution.form.editable.list</field>
            <field name="model">member.contribution</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="contribution_view_form"/> <!-- ref = 'module_name.form_view_id'-->
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('group_data_team')])]"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                  <field name="contribution_employee" position="attributes">
                      <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
                  </field>
            </field>
         </record>
```

like this you can modify the field attributes when a specific user logs in.

Comment: And what if i don't want to restrict it by group. I want to restrict field access by field value. If user is selected in `forbriden_user` field I want to restrict this user from writing to some of the fields.

Comment: ok, then simply inherit the form 2) inherit the field 3) then apply attrs like below. <field name="contribution_employee" position="attributes">
                      <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly':[('forbidden_user','=','some_value')]}</attribute>
                  </field>

Comment: thats the problem. What should be at `some_value`? I tried `uid` and `user.id`. Both doesn't work.

Comment: ok, if both are not working.. then try context.get('uid') in place of some_value. As the context will store the current uid

Comment: I get error: `"name 'context' is not defined" while evaluating`

Comment: `<field name="my_field" attrs="{'readonly': [('forbidden_user', '=', 'context.get('uid')')]}"/>`

Comment: remove the quotes around context.

Comment: then it says that `undefined name context`

Comment: Using `attrs` is not a secure option anyway. It will make the field _apear_ to be read only, but a sophisticated user can easily change the value by making it editable in developer tools or by using Odoo's web API directly.