# How to create access rights in HR module and every other module in ODOO 8.0?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, access-rights

Please explain how to create access rights . I am unable to understand groups creating process. Thank you .

Comment: this might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7/22534350#22534350

Answer (score 1):

If it does not work when your user is in the group Administration/Settings, it's probably because you changed the default access rights rules. Normally, it should work out-of-the-box, unless you changed the access rights rules.

You can investigate by checking this:

- set the admin user in the group "Technical Features"
- reload to get all menus
- Go to the menu Settings/Users/Groups
- Check the group Administration / Access Rights
- In the "Access Rights" tab of this group, you should see a line with object Users having "Create Access" checked
  Then, check the group "Administration / Settings"
- In the "Inherited" tab, you should see a line with Group Name "Access Rights".

  if you learn more then this link refer https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html