# How to create security groups in a right way in Odoo8?

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-8

**Introduction**

I've created a new category of security groups, and I've created several groups which belong to it.

My purpose is that the user who creates a new user, has to interact only with the groups I've created, not the default ones of *Sales*, *Purchases*, *Accounting*, etc... For example, if you belong to a group I've created, named *Controller*, it implies that you're going to belong also to the groups *base.group_user*, *account.group_account_invoice*, *purchase.group_purchase_user* and *stock.group_stock_manager*.

**Code**

This is the code of two of my groups (named *Controller* and *CFO*):

```
<record id="group_my_controller" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Controller</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[
        (4, ref('base.group_user')),
        (4, ref('account.group_account_invoice')),
        (4, ref('purchase.group_purchase_user')),
        (4, ref('stock.group_stock_manager')),
    ]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="group_my_cfo" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">CFO</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[
        (4, ref('base.group_user')),
        (4, ref('base.group_sale_manager')),
        (4, ref('stock.group_stock_manager')),
        (4, ref('account.group_account_manager')),
        (4, ref('purchase.group_purchase_manager')),
        (4, ref('share.group_share_user')),
        (4, ref('base.group_system')),
        (4, ref('project.group_project_manager')),
        (4, ref('base.group_document_user')),
        (4, ref('base.group_hr_manager')),
        (4, ref('marketing.group_marketing_manager')),
        (4, ref('base.group_website_designer')),
    ]"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

This works well, if I create a user and I set it as *Controller* for example, the permissions of *Accounting*, *Purchases* and *Stock* are automatically filled in with the specified ones.

**The problem**

The problem is when you set an user as *CFO* and save, and then change your mind and set it as *Controller*. When you save, the user keeps the groups of *CFO*, instead of moving to the groups of *Controller*. I think that is because CFO ones are less restrictive, because if you do this process the other way around, the permissions of *Controller* are rightly moved to *CFO*.

How can I achieve my purpose? Any ideas, please?

Comment: might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7/22534350#22534350

Comment: Thank you @Odedra. I've read the post and the links you've recommended inside it, unfortunately, this is not the same case. In fact, I've tried to achieve my purpose overwriting many2many `implied_ids` using `6,0,[ref(group1),ref(group2),etc...]` instead of `4`, but I'm getting same problem. Any ideas, please?