# AccessError when users edit many2one field in custom module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I created a custom module to add some fields into Partner data. Everything seems to work well but no admin users can't edit many2one fields. It shows the following message (as if any permissions configurations were wrong with that model):

[image]

**After doing what you asked, this is what happens:**

This is the error I get:

```
Exception: Fall\xf3 el m\xf3dulo cargando cant_neg_dir: no se pudo procesar el archivo cant_neg_dir/security/ir.model.access.csv: Line 1 : No se han encontrado registros coincidentes para id. externo 'group_name_test_user' en el campo 'Object'
```

And this is what I have in my files:

**ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_sector_user,sector.user,group_name_test_user,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

**cant_dir_security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_name_test">
            <field name="name">Management</field> 
            <field name="sequence">7</field>
        </record>
        <record id="group_name_test_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">User</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>
        <record id="group_name_test_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_name_test"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_name_test_user'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**cant_neg_dir.py**

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv, orm
from openerp import models


class poligono(models.Model):
    _name = "poligono"
    _rec_name= "poligono_name"
    _columns = {
        'poligono_name': fields.char('Polígono', required=True),   
}  

class sector(models.Model):
    _name = "sector"
    _rec_name= "sector_name"
    _columns = {
        'sector_name': fields.char('Sector', required=True),   
}   

class municipio(models.Model):
    _name = "municipio"
    _rec_name= "municipio_name"
    _columns = {
        'municipio_name': fields.char('Municipio', required=True),   
}
```

Again, thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give security access right to new object.

We can do it via code. For example:

```
access_sector,sector.user,model_sector,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

For more details [security/ir.model.access.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7/22534350#22534350) and [Odoo Security Documentation.](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html)

**EDIT**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_sector,sector.user,model_sector,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

**EDIT**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_sector_user,sector.user,your_module_name.group_name_test_user,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

And make sure openerp.py file will be look like following position file name

```
cant_dir_security.xml
ir.model.access.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!

I don't get that... Do I need to add that to my .py model code?

Comment: Nope. You need to create a folder name with *security* and in it, need to create *ir.model.access.csv* and placed answer code. Do not forget to mentioned file in *__openerp__.py* I have answered in very clearly in given link. You only need to change line with answered line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Odebra, but now I am getting error in Line 1, when installing the module.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Odebra, but now I am getting error in Line 1, when installing the module:

Line 1 : access_sector

Comment: You misunderstood. I have edited my answer try with it. First row will be label of fields and second row will be values of it and so on.

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: What error are you facing now ? Please update it with your question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest Odreda. Here you go: Exception: Fall\xf3 el m\xf3dulo cargando cant_neg_dir: no se pudo procesar el archivo cant_neg_dir/security/ir.model.access.csv: Line 1 : No se han encontrado registros coincidentes para id. externo 'group_name_test_user' en el campo 'Object'

I edited my question for further details. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer. We should use *module_name.xml_id*