# Custom module and creating groups in odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I'm working with odoo 10 on windows. I've created a new custom module now I want to add some  menus of my costum modules to certains users.

I'm new to odoo so my question is can I do that by creating group, associate the menus to my group then add the users to the group (I trid that but it did not work, when I log in with the user I find nothing). 
I've search on the web and I found that I need to creat my groups trough ir.model.access.csv (security folder) with this : id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_testmod_test,access_testmod_test,model_testmod_test,,1,1,1,1. 
Unfourtunately, I did not quite understand how can I do that and what should I write in some fields.
So can someone please give me a good tutorial that I can use, with examples, witch shows me how to create diffrents groups and adde users to it and add also some of the menus of my custom module to it.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-security-groups-odoo/

Comment: I too beginner in odoo the above link, this link helped me to create access rules and security, groups, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7

Answer (score 1):

so I tried this code but it did not work with me maybe I did it wrong here what I did : I created a file securuty.xml in my security folder with contain the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <data noupdate="0">
       <!-- Creating a Group Category -->        
       <record id="evaluation_subj" model="ir.module.category">
           <field name="name">evaluation subjective</field>
           <field name="sequence">1</field>
       </record>
       <!-- Adding a Group to the Group Category -->
       <record id="group_eval_subj" model="res.groups">
           <field name="name">Groupe Evaluation Subjective</field>
           <field name="evaluation_subj" ref="evaluation subjective"/>
           <!-- Adding Rights of existing Groups -->
           <field name="implied_ids"
                  eval="[(4, ref('base.group_system')), (4,ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
       </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Then in the file pnc_menus.xml (I have a file called pnc_menus.xml where I created all of my menus) I added the groups field to this menu:

`<menuitem name="Parties Prenantes" id="pnc_evaluation_stakeholders"
         action="pncevaluation_partieprenante" parent="pnc_documents" sequence="40" groups="base.group_system"/>`

Then in csv file of my security folder I added this :
`id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
eval_group,groupe_evaluation,pnc_evaluation_stakeholders,group_eval_subj,1,1,1,1`
When I updated my module I have an error saying "csv file could not be proccessed"

Answer (score 0):

Creating group category and group

**security/security.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
       <data noupdate="0">
           <!-- Creating a Group Category -->        
           <record id="category_name" model="ir.module.category">
               <field name="name">Name</field>
               <field name="sequence">1</field>
           </record>
           <!-- Adding a Group to the Group Category -->
           <record id="group_name" model="res.groups">
               <field name="name">Group Name</field>
               <field name="category_id" ref="category_name"/>
               <!-- Adding Rights of existing Groups -->
               <field name="implied_ids"
                      eval="[(4, ref('base.group_system')), (4,ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
           </record>
        </data>
    </openerp>
```

Adding a group to an existing menu (base.group_system)

```
<menuitem name="Name" id="id_name" parent="module.menu_id" action="module.action_id" 
groups="base.group_system"/>
```

**security/ir.model.access.csv**

Give your group access to your model

```
access_anything,classname,model_classname,group_id,1,1,1,1
```

for example (base. is added because model_ir_property is not from the own module)

```
access_ir_property1,ir_property,base.model_ir_property,your_new_group_id,1,1,1,1
```

Go to Settings->Groups, select your new group, press "Edit" and add users at page "Users".

Comment: Thank you I'll test it and give the feed-back

Comment: Manu W. so I tried this code but it did not work with me maybe I did it wrong here what I did : I created a file securuty.xml in my security folder with contain the following : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: <odoo>
       <data noupdate="0">
           <!-- Creating a Group Category -->        
           <record id="evaluation_subj" model="ir.module.category">
               <field name="name">evaluation subjective</field>
               <field name="sequence">1</field>
           </record>
           <!-- Adding a Group to the Group Category -->
        >

Comment: <record id="group_eval_subj" model="res.groups">
               <field name="name">Groupe Evaluation Subjective</field>
               <field name="evaluation_subj" ref="evaluation subjective"/>
               <!-- Adding Rights of existing Groups -->
               <field name="implied_ids"
                      eval="[(4, ref('base.group_system')), (4,ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
           </record>
        </data>
    </odoo

Comment: Then in the file pnc_menus.xml I added the groips field : <menuitem name="Parties Prenantes" id="pnc_evaluation_stakeholders"
   action="pncevaluation_partieprenante" parent="pnc_documents" sequence="40" groups="base.group_system"/>

Comment: Then in csv file I added this : id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
eval_group,groupe_evaluation,pnc_evaluation_stakeholders,group_eval_subj,1,1,1,1

Comment: Wen I updated my module I have an error saying "csv file could not be proccessed" so Can you help me pls

Comment: Could you put your code into a new answer, cause its quite hard to read it in several comments.

Comment: Manu W. I put my code in an answer. Can you please tell me what I did wrong

Comment: I can't add a comment at your post cause i got not enough reputation.
So for me everything looks fine, but i don't know if you choose these two right: groupe_evaluation,pnc_evaluation_stakeholders
the classname should be e.g. account.account or account.invoice and the model_classname like account.model_account_account or account.model_account_invoice, if the model is in your own module you need only model_classname. The classname is e.g. class AccountInvoice(models.Model): so the classname would be account.invoice.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to put account I have my custom module pnc_evaluation and I want to associate the menu stakeholders to my group. I still don't understand why I need to put this  eval="[(4, ref('base.group_system')), (4,ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/> what those fields means. I asked the question again here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349170/creating-security-groups-for-a-custom-module-in-odoo-10/44353269?noredirect=1#comment75715629_44353269

Comment: You dont need to use eval="... this is just the way how to add rights from existing groups, if needed.