# Reports visibility in Open-ERP 7

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, rml

In one of custom module I created some new Reports and screens but those reports and screens are showing only in Super Administrator login. Now I want to display those reports to every user, to achieve this what I need to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to do assign access rights to other user also
This document help you :

http://openerp-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04_security.html

and also this is help you:

[OpenERP 7 How to give users access to custom module in OpenERP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368935/openerp-7-how-to-give-users-access-to-custom-module-in-openerp-7)